# Bad SQL grammar -The column name was not found in this ResultSet?

Tags: java, spring-jdbc

Hello I am using a JDBC query and I am having this error but I don't understand why, or what exactly is the meaning of this error and what is wrong with the query.
The query is as below

```
private List<StatisticsLog>  runStatistics(Integer partnerId, LocalDate ldStart, LocalDateTime ldtEnd, String statType)
    {
        return jdbcTemplate.query("SELECT S.APP_ID, S.LOG_TYPE, ACC.CONTACT_PERSON_FIRST_NAME, ACC.CONTACT_PERSON_LAST_NAME, ACV.VERSION_APP_NAME, "
                + "'" + statType.trim() + "' STATTYPE, "
                + "ACV.APP_CATALOG_ID, ACV.APP_CATALOG_VERSION_ID, ACV.VERSION, ACV.UPDATED_AT, ACV.VERSION_LOGO_EXT, ACV.HAS_LOGO, "
                + "LANG.LANGUAGE_NAME_SHORT, LANG.LANGUAGE_ID , S.count, S.PARTNER_ID, APP.CREATED_AT "
                + "FROM (SELECT partner_id, log_type, app_id, language_id, count(*) as count FROM public.statistics_log "
                + " WHERE partner_id = ? "
                + " and logged_at between ? and ? "
                + "group by 1, log_type, app_id, language_id) as S "
                + "INNER JOIN APP_CATALOG_ACCOUNT ACP ON ACP.APP_CATALOG_SERIAL_ID = S.APP_ID "
                + "INNER JOIN APP_CATALOG APP ON APP.APP_CATALOG_SERIAL_ID = S.APP_ID "
                + "INNER JOIN ACCOUNT ACC ON ACC.ACCOUNT_ID = S.PARTNER_ID "
                + "INNER JOIN APP_CATALOG_VERSION ACV on ACV.APP_CATALOG_SERIAL_ID = APP.APP_CATALOG_SERIAL_ID AND ACV.STATUS = 3 "
                + "INNER JOIN LANGUAGE LANG ON LANG.LANGUAGE_ID = ACV.LANGUAGE_ID "
                + "ORDER BY S.count desc ",
                new Object[] { partnerId, ldStart, ldtEnd }, new StatisticsLogRowMapper());
    }
```

and I am getting the error from this column  `CREATED_AT`  that is part of the app catalog, and I think it should be there, also for more detailed also I will attach `StatisticsLogRowMapper`

```
public class StatisticsLogRowMapper implements RowMapper<StatisticsLog>
{
    @Override
    public StatisticsLog mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException
    {
        StatisticsLog stat = new StatisticsLog();

        stat.setAppId(rs.getInt("APP_ID"));
        stat.setPartnerId(rs.getInt("PARTNER_ID"));
        stat.setCount(rs.getLong("COUNT"));
        stat.setCreatedAt(rs.getTimestamp("CREATED_AT").toLocalDateTime());
        stat.setPartnerFirstName(rs.getString("CONTACT_PERSON_FIRST_NAME"));
        stat.setPartnerLastName(rs.getString("CONTACT_PERSON_LAST_NAME"));
        stat.setAppNameDefault(rs.getString("VERSION_APP_NAME"));
        stat.setAppCatalogId(rs.getInt("APP_CATALOG_ID"));
        stat.setStatType(rs.getString("STATTYPE"));
        stat.setLogType(LogTypeEnum.valueOf(rs.getString("LOG_TYPE").trim()));
        stat.setAppCatalogVersionId(rs.getInt("APP_CATALOG_VERSION_ID"));
        stat.setVersion(rs.getInt("VERSION"));
        stat.setUpdatedAt(rs.getDate("UPDATED_AT"));
        stat.setVersionLogoExt(rs.getString("VERSION_LOGO_EXT"));
        stat.setHasLogo(rs.getBoolean("HAS_LOGO"));
        stat.setLanguageNameShort(rs.getString("LANGUAGE_NAME_SHORT"));
        stat.setLanguageId(rs.getInt("LANGUAGE_ID"));

        return stat;
    }
}
```

THE ERROR IS: "PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [SELECT S.APP_ID, S.LOG_TYPE, ACC.CONTACT_PERSON_FIRST_NAME, ACC.CONTACT_PERSON_LAST_NAME, ACV.VERSION_APP_NAME, 'days30' STATTYPE, ACV.APP_CATALOG_ID, ACV.APP_CATALOG_VERSION_ID, ACV.VERSION, ACV.UPDATED_AT, ACV.VERSION_LOGO_EXT, ACV.HAS_LOGO, LANG.LANGUAGE_NAME_SHORT, S.count, S.PARTNER_ID FROM (SELECT partner_id, log_type, app_id, language_id, count(*) as count FROM public.statistics_log  WHERE logged_at between ? and ? group by 1, log_type, app_id, language_id, partner_id) as S INNER JOIN APP_CATALOG_ACCOUNT ACP ON ACP.APP_CATALOG_SERIAL_ID = S.APP_ID INNER JOIN APP_CATALOG APP ON APP.APP_CATALOG_SERIAL_ID = S.APP_ID INNER JOIN ACCOUNT ACC ON ACC.ACCOUNT_ID = S.PARTNER_ID  INNER JOIN APP_CATALOG_VERSION ACV on ACV.APP_CATALOG_SERIAL_ID = APP.APP_CATALOG_SERIAL_ID AND ACV.STATUS = 3 INNER JOIN LANGUAGE LANG ON LANG.LANGUAGE_ID = ACV.LANGUAGE_ID ORDER BY S.count desc ]; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column name CREATED_AT was not found in this ResultSet."

> IN THE ERROR SEEMS THIS FIELD ISN'T THERE SOMEHOW

If you have any idea what may be wrong or thing I can try please don't hesitate to comment, I would appreciate d even the smallest help thank you.

Comment: I see no errrors here.

Comment: Please post the exception stacktrace of your error

Comment: You seem to be selecting a column called `CREATED_AT`, so, assuming this is the actual code, there is no reason to expect that this column would not be available in the result set.

Comment: Perhaps retrieve the `rs.getMetaData()`, loop over it and print out the column names? This could give a hint which columns are available in your resultset and why it won't take `CREATED_AT`?

Comment: @TheWhiteRabbit so isn't in the result set, but I mean that's what error is trying to tell us, but I don't get it why seems from the console, this part is missing  `APP.CREATED_AT` , and that is really strange

Comment: Did you add this column later to the query and did you recompile your code? Perhaps you're still running an older version of the query? Or classpath issues? I don't think it's code related though.

Comment: No it has was there from the beginning,

Comment: Functions the SQL if you execute it from some SQL tool? If yes, is the label of the given column CREATED_AT?

Comment: Sorry @Michal didn't understand what you mean

Comment: What I am trying to say is that the column name is not correct, for whatever reason. Therefore I would execute the SQL using e.g. one of those https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/PostgreSQL_Clients and when it executes I would look at the column name in result.

Comment: Alternatively I would add into SQL something like `APP.CREATED_AT as CREATED_AT`.  In my understanding the SQL executes ok, the error happens when getting data from ResultSet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see there is an error in line 2 of the query -  + "'" + statType.trim() + "' STATTYPE, ", right after the quote. STATTYPE does not have a table reference and is appended with a string. That could be another issue. I cannot comment on the question as I dont have enough reputation.

Comment: STATTYPE is the column alias for the textual value which is being selected, in this case 'days30'. It doesn't need a table reference, and looks like valid syntax.